# How do I empty variable/turn variable back to undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a case where I check if a variable is undefined. in some instances I would like to turn the variable undefined again, so that it returns as undefined? Would this be considered bad practice?

:D/ code sample!

```
if (loc1 == undefined){
    loc1 = loc.title
    }
else if(loc2 == undefined){
    loc2 = loc.title
}
else{
//here I want loc1 and loc2 to turn undefined again!
}
```

Comment: Just set the variables to `undefined`.

Comment: @amnotiam: Ferpectly. (Also, all you people who recommended `delete` should probably `delete` your answers instead of leaving them there to accumulate downvotes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
var test = 1;
test = undefined;
```

Comment: The identifier `undefined` may have been assigned a value other than `undefined` (rare but possible). To guarantee a value of undefined, `var test = void 0;` might be better. Hard to see that that is better than setting it to `null` or `false` or some other specific value.

Comment: @RobG: I like your suggestion to use the `void` operator, but I'd suggest that if there's any question about the purity of the environment, it should be directly tested, and if corrupted it should be corrected.

Comment: I think you'd have greater problems elsewhere if `undefined` is reassigned. So this can be safely ignored.